# javascript disable text box with if statement

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use javascript to detect if "remote_server" is set to 0, if it is then disable the text box "ftp_hostname".  If I uncomment the alert it works, however the field is still not disabled.

Text box:

```
<label for="ftp_hostname">
FTP Hostname
</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['ftphost']; ?>" class="required" name="ftp_hostname" class="text">
```

Javascript:

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("remote_server")[0]
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if ( strUser == 0 ) {
document.getElementsByName("ftp_hostname")[0].disabled
//alert("selected!");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
document.getElementsByName("ftp_hostname")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `=true`

```
document.getElementsByName("ftp_hostname")[0].disabled=true;
```